# look for a metric for a two variable system

Tags: probability, experimental-mathematics

I have a series of experiments for different objects
from the experiments
let me put it in an abstract way
there is a condition A
for a specific object O
the success rate/percentage is p(A)
generally speaking, for most of values of A
(A=a1, A=a2, A=a3.....blabla) p(A) is 100%
but for some of A, p(A) is 0 and for some of A
p(A) is between 0 and 1

so there are 2 variables: object and condition
for each object, the success rate may for different conditions
now I want to compare different object in terms of success rate
how to define a metric for the comparison?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For each object $O$ you have a vector of numbers between $0$ and $1$, namely success rates for A=a1, A=a2, etc.

The problem becomes: how to define a metric on the set of vectors $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with all entries between $0$ and $1$? There is no canonical answer. The two simplest metrics are
$$d_1(x,y)=|x_1-y_1|+\dots +|x_n-y_n|$$
and
$$d_\infty (x,y)=\max(|x_1-y_1|, \dots , |x_n-y_n|)$$